¿Porque OneHotEncoder tira ValueError: Columns must be same length as key?
Estoy trantando de hacer one hot encoding en algunas columnas de un Dataframe usando sklearn.
Cuando trato de hacerlo tengo el siguiente error: ValueError:
Columns must be same length as key
EncoderOH = sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()

    
X_train[Ord_cols] = EncoderOR.fit_transform(X_train[Ord_cols])    
X_train[Nom_cols] = EncoderOH.fit_transform(X_train[Nom_cols])

No entiendo porque el error salta con el OneHot Encoding, pero no con con el OrdinalEncoder
